# WebServiceHost plugin's Kestrel hosting failed

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

Anyone ever got this issue because I never seen that before. Please let me know the details on this issue. I hosted windows service in server where Web API produce result set but When I am starting windows service I am getting this exception.

> [Fatal] WebServiceHost plugin's Kestrel hosting failed. Web content
> won't be served. System.ArgumentException: Valid listening port has to
> be defined.

Comment: Can you show Program.cs?

Comment: Does your error message is `System.ArgumentException: Invalid listening port has to be defined.`?

Comment: yes, I posted same.

Comment: It seems you used the wrong port or the port has been used. Please modify the port number and try again.  `serverOptions.Listen(IPAddress.Loopback, 5000);` modify the 5000 to another port. More details about how to set the Kestrel setting, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-3.1#kestrel-options).